# Same Height Elements but responsive variation

Tags: javascript, html

I found another question on this page about having two elements with the same height even if one of them doesn't have enough elements to cover the entire area. It works really fine but after reaching a max width of 600px I would like to disable this code, like getting back to height: auto; I'm trying to solve this but without any result. Any suggestion? here's actual javascript code.

HTML

```
<div id="section3a" data-same-height="blocks-resize">
</div>

<div id="section3b" data-same-height="blocks-resize">
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var equalize = function () {
    var disableOnMaxWidth = 0; // 767 for bootstrap

    var grouped = {};
    var elements = $('*[data-same-height]');

    elements.each(function () {
        var el = $(this);
        var id = el.attr('data-same-height');

        if (!grouped[id]) {
            grouped[id] = [];
        }

        grouped[id].push(el);
    });

    $.each(grouped, function (key) {
        var elements = $('*[data-same-height="' + key + '"]');

        elements.css('height', '');

        var winWidth = $(window).width();

        if (winWidth <= disableOnMaxWidth) {
            return;
        }

        var maxHeight = 0;

        elements.each(function () {
            var eleq = $(this);
            maxHeight = Math.max(eleq.height(), maxHeight);
        });

        elements.css('height', maxHeight + "px");
    });
};

var timeout = null;

$(window).resize(function () {
    if (timeout) {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = null;
    }

    timeout = setTimeout(equalize, 250);
});
equalize();
});
```

Thanks to everyone!

Comment: Try looking into css solutions. flexbox is probably a good place to start https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ `align-items: stretch`

Comment: but I need to solve it this way:( already finished my site like that:(.. @Seth McClaine